# Can I round this equation here in Excel? =SUM(E6:E13)/4

Tags: excel, rounding

I've found answers to do with sums but the only use + or * in their examples so unsure whether I could do it with the '/4' at the end. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes you can!  Just try it and you should see it works :) .  If not, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41748144/edit) to add details of what you have tried.

Comment: Have you *tried* rounding it?

Answer (score 0):

`=ROUND(SUM(E6:E13),2)` will round to two digits, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Round it to integer (or, instead of `0`, use your preferred decimal precision):

```
=Round(Sum(E6:E13)/4,0)
```

Round up:

```
=Int(Sum(E6:E13)/4)+1
```

Round down

```
=Int(Sum(E6:E13)/4)
```